# How to change images src automatically

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to code a traffic light sequence that will loop through the images automatically. However, I have a small problem with the automatic changing. Could you help with where I am going wrong?

```
var images = ["red.png",
"redamber.png",
"orange.png",
"green.png"];
setTimeout("changelight()",1000);
var index = 0;

function changeImage()
{
document.getElementById("img").src= images[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Please check the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/27jygopz/1/)

Try this

```
var index = 0;
function changeImage()
{
if (index > 3) index = 0;
document.getElementById("img").src= images[index];
index++;
}

var images = ["red.png",
"redamber.png",
"orange.png",
"green.png"];
setInterval(changeImage,1000);
```

Comment: Use setInterval function not setTimeout to do it regularly.

Comment: @Maurice It is order of code. I updated my answer see the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/27jygopz/1/

Answer (score 1):

You probably intended
`document.getElementById("img").src= images[`**index**`];`

And make sure that index is updated

Comment: Very lax answer. And isn't solving his problem.

Answer (score 1):

You were mostly there, but there were a couple of little things.

Firstly, you were calling a function called `changeLight`, but the function was called `changeImage`.  You also need to change the image source attribute to `images[index]`, and then increase that value each time.

The line `index = (index + 1) % 4;` adds 1 to index, but will only allow it to get as high as 3.  If it reaches 4 then the `% 4` at the end will set it to 0.

For reference, see [the remainder description on this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

You were also using `setTimeout` which only runs once.  If you use `setInterval` it works exactly the same but repeats.

```
var images = ["red.png",
    "redamber.png",
    "orange.png",
    "green.png"];

setInterval(changeLight, 1000);

var index = 0;

function changeLight() {
    document.getElementById("img").src = images[index];
    index = (index + 1) % 4;
}
```

The only other thing that may be an issue is that I don't know if your image actually does have an ID of `img`.  If it doesn't then you'll need to add that.

Comment: I like the way you use modulus. +1

Answer (score 0):

**You did some typical beginner mistakes:**

1. Your `function name` isn't related with `the one in the timer`.
2. You probably want an `interval` instead of a `single timeout`.
3. You have to use a `querySelector` to select a DOM by tag.
4. To go through an `array` you have to use variable `increment` combined with an `if` check.

*Please read the doc's:* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

```
var images = ["red.png", "redamber.png", "orange.png", "green.png"];
var index = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    document.querySelector("img").src= images[index];
    /* common - easy to understand - way:
    if (index > images.length - 1) index = 0;
    ...
    index++;
    */
    index = index == images.length - 1 ? index = 0 : index + 1 // casual way - toggle bool -
    console.log(index);
}, 1000);
```

**Example**: https://jsfiddle.net/27jygopz/

Answer (score -1):

```
var images = ["red.png", "redamber.png", "orange.png", "green.png"];
setTimeout("changelight()",1000);
var index = 0;

function changeImage()
{
    index = (index + 1) % 4;
    document.getElementById("img").src= images[index];
}
```